# Android Menu Popover causes Parentview to jump up

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on some legacy code and instead of using Bottomsheet, they use popover menu(which is a Framelayout), to jump from the bottom to select few option. My Parent Activity where the popover gets inflated, is pushed up . How do I fix this?

Please note: Although using BottomSheet is a better option, for now due to time constraint, I will have to stick with old Menu poup.

Comment: `for now due to time constraint,` is it really going to take that long to change it ? it takes a few minutes to create a bottom sheet dialog

Comment: Yeah agree, will give it a try as it a clean option